# Repeated prints from loop

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program similar to the game Mastermind. I am having an issue in my while loop where it constantly prints "You got " + str(correct) + " correct!"

```
import random
import replit

def useranswer(input):
  userinput.append(input)
  return input

number = 0
answer = 0
guesses = 0
correct = 0 
x = 0
userinput = []
generation = []
c = []

replit.clear()
for i in range(0,4):
  num = random.randrange(1,9)
  generation.append(num)

for i in range(0,4):
  answer = str(input('Give me a number: '))
  useranswer(answer)
print(generation)

while userinput != generation:
  guesses += 1
  for i in range(0,4):
    if generation[i] == userinput[i]:
      correct += 1
  print("You got " + str(correct) + " correct! ")
  correct = 0

if guesses==1:
      print("Good job! You became the MASTERMIND in one turn!")
else:
    print("You have become the MASTERMIND in " + str(guesses) + " tries!")
```

Comment: You are not asking for more input in the loop.  It just keeps using the original input over and over.  You might consider writing a function to get the next line of input.  Also, you're doing `str(input(...))`, but `input` always returns a string already.  What you need here is `int(input(...))`.

Comment: Unclear why you need a while loop at all. You're never modifying the guesses or generation lists

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to exit the `while` loop after printing the line `print("You got " + str(correct) + " correct! ")` then you'll need to do something within the `while` loop to make the check not true.

Right now if `userinput != generation` is true then it will loop forever because nothing in the loop ever changes that to be false.

You need to get the player's input within the while loop if you want it to keep looping until something happens, otherwise an `if` statement might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Ive made couple of changes to your code. Take a look at it

1. Removed def userinput().
2. Moved userinput inside the while loop.

```
import random
import replit


number = 0
answer = 0
guesses = 0

x = 0
userinput = []
generation = []
c = []

replit.clear()
for i in range(0,4):
  num = random.randrange(1,9)
  generation.append(num)

while userinput != generation:
  guesses += 1
  correct = 0
  userinput = []
  for i in range(0,4):
    answer = int(input('Give me a number: '))
    userinput.append(answer)
  for i in range(0,4):
      if generation[i] == userinput[i]:
        correct += 1
  print("You got ",correct, " correct! ")

if guesses==1:
      print("Good job! You became the MASTERMIND in one turn!")
else:
    print("You have become the MASTERMIND in " ,guesses, " tries!")
```